# Аргумент функции зависящий от флага

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например нужно найти массовый расход через трубопровод для жидкости и газа. Где-то ранее объявлен класс `Fluid` со свойством `density` и другими такими, что создание класса Gas не будет подразумевать наследование `Fluid`. Тогда класс `Gas` будет иметь своё свойство `density`.

Тогда получается так:

```
v = velocity  # не является свойством какого-либо из классов
F = section_area  # не является свойством какого-либо из классов 

def fluid_mass_flow(fluid):
   return fluid.density * v * F

def gas_mass_flow(gas):
   return gas.density * v *F
```

Это очевидно дублирование кода (по сути это методы классов). Есть ли способ с помощью какого-то флага принимать какой класс я хочу использовать и уже для него определять расход? Что-то вроде `q = mass_flow("working mass")`.

Либо я неверно создал класс, но подразумевается, что площадь поперечного сечения и скорость не являются свойствами этих рабочих тел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если интерфейсы объектов совместимы, то всеравно что вы там передаете.

```
def mass_flow(gas_or_fluid):
   return gas_or_fluid.density * v *F
```

Если интерфейсы не совместимы, то isinstace

```
def mass_flow(gas_or_fluid):
   if isinstace(gas_or_fluid, GasClass):
        return gas_or_fluid.density * v *F

   elif isinstace(gas_or_fluid, FluidClass):
        return gas_or_fluid.density * u *F
```

Comment: Что подразумевает совместимость интерфейсов? По сути вторая реализация ничем не отличается от предложенного мной, такое же печальное дублирование кода. Ну и например если есть переменная v для газа и переменная u для жидкости, надо вызвать в зависимости от класса разные переменные и подставить в одинаковые функции

Comment: Потому что формулы одинаковые, если формулы были бы разные то можно их там ставить.

Comment: Ну вот u и v - теперь формулы разные

Comment: Просто не совсем ясно откуда нам знать какую u и v брать, это же аргументы

Comment: Это не аргументы в вашем случае, ну вот смотрите что за класс. В зависимости от класса и смотрите